# Flutter doctor in windows Unable to determine Android Studio version

Tags: flutter

I am setting up flutter env on windows. I installed the latest Android Stuido and run flutter doctor got this error.

[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
X Unable to determine Android Studio version.

Is there anyone facing this problem? not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Same happens on Hedgehog, Android Studio release.